# (Errno 50) Protocol not available when making requests using pyscript

Tags: python-requests, pyscript

I've been trying to convert a Python app that I made into a webapp so that it can be easily used by others. Part of the app involves users entering their username and a request being sent to an api with their username. I'm using the boilerplate website provided by PyScript to test things out.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
      <title> Polyglot - Piratical PyScript</title>
      <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.11.2/core.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Polyglot    ➡️ ‍☠️</h1>
    <p>Translate English into Pirate speak...</p>
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Type English here..." />
    <button py-click="find_game">Find Game</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="py" src="./test.py" config="./pyscript.toml"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.py**

```
import requests
from pyscript import document


def find_game(event):
    input_text = document.querySelector("#user")
    username = input_text.value
    
    custom_headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    }
    
        

    last_game = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers=custom_headers)

 


    output_div = document.querySelector("#output")
    output_div.innerText = last_game
```

**pyscript.toml**

```
packages = ["requests", "ssl"]
```

When I start a static webserver using `python3 -m http.server` and press the Find Game button, the following error pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 67, in create_connection
    _set_socket_options(sock, socket_options)
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 100, in _set_socket_options
    sock.setsockopt(*opt)
OSError: [Errno 50] Protocol not available

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xd90f88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 50] Protocol not available

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /headers (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xd90f88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 50] Protocol not available'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<exec>", line 58, in find_game
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /headers (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xd90f88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 50] Protocol not available'))
```

Most of the similar posts I've come across online talk about Dockers, something I'm not too familiar about so I'm not sure whether the issue is with the way PyScript is implemented or my code.

I've also tried using other libraries to make HTTP requests such as urllib3 but the same error occurs.

Comment: See Jeff Glass's comment [here from December 7 at 16:12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590382/how-to-install-the-pyscript-pyodide-module-in-python#comment136842561_77590382) since you are trying to use pyscript to do connections and it seems you haven't found [this post](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/91#issuecomment-1114253813) and discussion there after it. -- key quote from there: "requests or in fact urllib3 because the entire networking stack does not translate to a browser environment very well."